# label_smoothing in "The Annotated Transformer"

Tags: nlp, transformer-model

In ["The Annotated Transformer"](http://nlp.seas.harvard.edu/2018/04/03/attention.html), label smoothing is implemented as the following:

```
class LabelSmoothing(nn.Module):
    "Implement label smoothing."
    def __init__(self, size, padding_idx, smoothing=0.0):
        super(LabelSmoothing, self).__init__()
        self.criterion = nn.KLDivLoss(size_average=False)
        self.padding_idx = padding_idx
        self.confidence = 1.0 - smoothing
        self.smoothing = smoothing
        self.size = size
        self.true_dist = None

    def forward(self, x, target):
        assert x.size(1) == self.size
        true_dist = x.data.clone()
        true_dist.fill_(self.smoothing / (self.size - 2))
        true_dist.scatter_(1, target.data.unsqueeze(1), self.confidence)
        true_dist[:, self.padding_idx] = 0
        mask = torch.nonzero(target.data == self.padding_idx)
        if mask.dim() > 0:
            true_dist.index_fill_(0, mask.squeeze(), 0.0)
        self.true_dist = true_dist
        return self.criterion(x, Variable(true_dist, requires_grad=False))
```

In particular, why it is

```
true_dist.fill_(self.smoothing / (self.size - 2))
```

Where does the 2 in `self.size - 2` come from?

And what is the purpose of `true_dist[:, self.padding_idx] = 0`